# Get folder name from path in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, path

I didn't find through searching in internet simple solution for this purpose which can be quickly integrated into my code. I propose my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this function from time to time, I need in my projects I decided to create a separate function for it. The code of it is below:

```
Function GetFolderNameFromPath(folderPath As String) As String

Dim lastPathSeparatorPosition As Long, folderPathLength As Long, folderNameLength As Long

lastPathSeparatorPosition = InStrRev(folderPath, Application.PathSeparator)
folderPathLength = Len(folderPath)
folderNameLength = folderPathLength - lastPathSeparatorPosition
GetFolderNameFromPath = Right(folderPath, folderNameLength)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this with a single line of code:

```
Function GetFolderNameFromPath(folderPath As String) As String
    GetFolderNameFromPath = Split(folderPath, Application.PathSeparator)(UBound(Split(folderPath, Application.PathSeparator)))
End Function
```

Comment: A nice solution to split the path into an array. Personally I prefer several code lines with meaningful variables instead of one long code line with several methods in it.

Comment: You'll find that the `Split` method can be very useful in returning portions of delimited strings.